# How to create stack trace for other process(out of process) when it crashes in google breakpad?

Tags: stack-trace, callstack, crash-dumps, google-breakpad, out-of-process

How to create stack trace for other process(out of process) when it crashes in google_breakpad?

i cant find good way. (OS : window / language : C++)

i want to find good way to use google_breakpad::CrashGenerationServer class.

help me please.

i use between client(requester), server(break pad server) ipc connection in google_breakpad.